# How to build a parent/child mapping for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to use the following mapping to index my data:

```
{  
  "mappings": {
   "chow-demo": {
    "properties": {
     "@fields": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "properties": {
        "asgid": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword"
        },
        "asid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "astid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "clfg": {
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "httpcode": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "oid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "onid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "ptrnr": {
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "pguid": {
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ptid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "sid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "src_url": {
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ts": {
          "type": "long"
        }
       }
      },
      "@timestamp": {
       "format": "dateOptionalTime",
       "type": "date"
      },
      "@message": {
       "type": "string"
      },
      "@source": {
       "type": "string"
      },
      "@type": {
       "analyzer": "keyword",
       "type": "string"
      },
      "@tags": {
       "type": "string"
      },
      "@source_host": {
       "type": "string"
      },
      "@source_path": {
       "type": "string"
      }
     }
    },
   "chow-clfg": {
    "_parent": {
     "type": "chow-demo"
    },
    "dynamic": "true",
    "properties": {
     "_ttl": {
      "enabled": true,
      "default": "1h"
     },
     "clfg": {
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "type": "string"
     },
     "@timestamp": {
      "format": "dateOptionalTime",
      "type": "date"
     },
     "count": {
      "type": "long"
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I tried to populate the parent type "chow-demo" without populating the child type "chow-clfg", and the document refused to index. (No documents were indexed into Elasticsearach)

When I take out the child mapping for "chow-clfg", it does indexing properly as usual. Hence I have the following question:

1. Is my mapping structure wrong?
2. Must the parent and child be indexed together at the same time before the data can be successfully indexed?

Really need help in this question for my project to progress! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, your mapping is wrong. The `_ttl` element should be one level higher in the `chow-clfg` type. In other words `_ttl` should be on the same level as `_parent`. However, I am not quite sure how this problem can affect your ability to index.
2. Parents and children don't have to be indexed together.

Comment: Yes! Thanks imotov! It affected my ability to index. Works after the first try!